# I've had an issue in getting transactions to work with linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
public void WriteTrans(Sale Sales)
{
    var m_db = DataContextFactory.CreateContext();
    try {
        m_db.Transaction.Connection.Open();
        using (var trans = m_db.Transaction.Connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

It is giving below error:

[image: this error show]

Comment: Usually, it's better to copy / paste or rewrite the error, so that it can be easily read and understood by people that could be willing to help you

Comment: Probably m_db.Transaction is null. or m_db.Transaction.Connection. This question is clearly demanding help for debugging.